# How to run javafx with .sh files?

Tags: java, linux, shell, javafx

I have two .sh files and one javafx jar.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8vUi.png)

I want to run the start.sh file when I open the javafx jar.

I want to run the exit.sh file when I exit the javafx jar.

How can I do this?

Comment: add a third script that calls them in sequence?

Comment: I want to call the  .sh files with javafx .

Comment: This is possible as well. Have a look at `ProcessBuilder`.